# slack api calls through python request library

Tags: python, python-requests, slack-api

I was making slack api calls through python library slackclient which is a wrapper around slack api. However, for some cases I need to make conventional api calls also with url and get/post method. I was trying to open a direct message channel with another user by my bot. The documentation - https://api.slack.com/methods/im.open says to  "Present these parameters as part of an application/x-www-form-urlencoded querystring or POST body. application/json is not currently accepted."

Now in python, I can write,

```
url = 'https://slack.com/api/im.open'
    headers = {'content-type':'x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    data = {'token':BOT_TOKEN, 'user':user_id, 'include_locale':'true','return_im':'true'}
    r= requests.post(url,headers,data )
    print r.text
```

The message I get is `{"ok":false,"error":"not_authed"}`

I know the message is "not authed" although I use my bot token and another user id, my hunch is that I'm sending the request in wrong format because I just wrote it some way reading the documentation. I'm not sure how to exactly send these requests.

Any help?

Comment: try setting `data` as `[('token', BOT_TOKEN), ('user', user_id), .....]` and then `response = requests.post(url, data, **headers)`

Comment: it worked. thanks @ArpitGoyal

Comment: should I post an answer so that you can upvote it?

Comment: yes, I'd be happy to do that @ArpitGoyal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the Content-Type header is `x-www-form-urlencoded` sending data in form of dictionary does not work. you can try something like this.

```
import requests

url = 'https://slack.com/api/im.open'
headers = {'content-type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded'}
data = [
 ('token', BOT_TOKEN),
 ('user', user_id),
 ('include_locale', 'true'),
 ('return_im', 'true')
]

r = requests.post(url, data, **headers)
print r.text
```

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter in `requests.post` is used for `data`, so in your request you're actually posting the `headers` dictionary. If you want to use `headers` you can pass arguments by name.

```
r= requests.post(url, data, headers=headers)
```

However this is not necessary in this case because `'x-www-form-urlencoded'` is the default when posting form data.